# How do i create a script element to include jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to write a script that will append the jquery cdn script
to the body of the document.

```
function addJquery() {
    url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js";
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
addJquery();
```

What am i doing wrong here

Comment: All the spaces on the far right between `j` and `s` won't help you

Comment: Sorry that was i typo.

Answer (score 4):

You can't add scripts to the body and have them execute. Late-loaded scripts must be loaded through the `head` element:

```
(function addJQuery() {
  var url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js";
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.url = url;
  script.onload = function() { addJQuery(); }
  document.head.appendChild(script);
}());
```

However, this loads jQuery regardless of whether it's already loaded, so that's no good. Here's what you generally want instead:

```
(function loadMyCode() {
  // do we have jquery? if not, load it.
  if (typeof jQuery === "undefined") {
    var url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js";
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.url = url;
    script.onload = function() {
       // this will run after jquery gets loaded
       loadMyCode();
    }
    document.head.appendChild(script);
    return;
  }

  // if we get here, we know we have jquery
  //
  // rest of the code goes here.
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way

```
(function () { 
var li = document.createElement('script'); 
li.type = 'text/javascript'; 
li.src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js";
li.async=true;
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
s.parentNode.insertBefore(li, s); 
})();
```

Comment: What is the safest fastest and most fail-proof way to incorperate  jquery.

Comment: Should i not use Googles CDN, i understand this to be a best practice.

Comment: It completely depends upon network's speed..you cant guaruntee it, that the js will load each time you request it..There can be many possibilities for js file not to be loaded i.e. if user's network speed is slow, or he losts the connectivity..Its always a good practice to use CDN...